# Deserialize XML element which could have different namespaces

Tags: php, xml, symfony, jms-serializer

I'm trying to get element from XML under one variable, where I'm having the same xml tree, but with another xml namespace prefix.

I've got a lot similar elements, and that would be annoying to write 3x the same classes or elements and validating if one of them is null (avoiding exceptions).

Using symfony 2.8, JMS/serializer 1.5.0

XML looks like this:

```xml
<Dokument xmlns:wnio="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2013/12/12/1410/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2013/12/12/1410/ http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2013/12/12/1410/schemat.xsd">
      <wnio:OpisDokumentu>
          ...
      </wnio:OpisDokumentu>
      ...
```

and like this:

```xml
<Dokument xmlns:pos="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/UPO/2008/05/09/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2013/12/12/1410/ http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2013/12/12/1410/schemat.xsd">
      <pos:OpisDokumentu>
          ...
      </pos:OpisDokumentu>
      ...
```

Right now I handle this by generating another elements and checking if one of them is not null. But writing next elements for another namespaces make my model library really huge.

```php
/**
  * @Serializer\Type("MyBundle\Model\OpisDokumentu")
  * @Serializer\XmlElement(namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2013/12/12/1410/")
  * @Serializer\SerializedName("OpisDokument")
  * @Serializer\Expose
  */
private $opisDokumentuWnio;

/**
  * @Serializer\Type("MyBundle\Model\OpisDokumentu")
  * @Serializer\XmlElement(namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/UPO/2008/05/09/")
  * @Serializer\SerializedName("OpisDokument")
  * @Serializer\Expose
  */
private $opisDokumentuPos;
...
//getters/setters
```

In this situation I've got object with 2 variables with another getter/setter like this:

```
Dokument:
    opisDokumentuWnio: ...
    opisDokumentuPos: null
...
```

Want to achieve only one variable regardless of changes to the namespace prefix:

```
Dokument:
    opisDokumentu: ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When an application has to deal with input that can be in one of a number of namespaces with very similar definitions, my advice is always to start by transforming the data into a common form using a single namespace (typically using XSLT), and then do the subsequent processing on that common form.